# Updating multiple records from database at once

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I just added the names of those undefined index in my edit_mision_vision.php. I have updated my code and it's working now. Thanks for the help :)

**update_mission_vision.php** // where the update happens and where the notice showed (but it is fixed now) that says vision, mission, and values are undefined

```
<?php
    $conn=mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
    mysql_select_db("alumni", $conn);
    if (! $conn)
    {
        DIE('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    if(isset($_POST['update']))
    {
    $vision = $_POST['vision'];
    $mission = $_POST['mission'];
    $values = $_POST['values']; 

    $query="UPDATE about SET description='$vision' WHERE title='Vision'";
    $retval = mysql_query( $query, $conn );
    $query1="UPDATE about SET description='$mission' WHERE title='Mission'";
    $retval = mysql_query( $query1, $conn );
    $query2="UPDATE about SET description='$values' WHERE title='Values'";
    $retval = mysql_query( $query2, $conn );

    if(! $retval )  {
        DIE('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Changes saved!!');
                    window.location.assign('/alumni/mission_vision.php');</script>";
    }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['cancel']))
    {
        header("Location: /alumni/admin_profile.php");
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

**edit_mission_vision.php** where i edit the mission, vision, and values description // *this is where i added the name="vision", name="mission", name="values" and that solved my problem.*

```
<form action="/alumni/admin/update_mission_vision.php" method="post">
<?php
    include_once 'db.php';
    $sql="SELECT * FROM about";
    $result_set=mysql_query($sql);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
    {
?>

<?php if($row['title']=='Vision') { ?>
 <label>Vision</labrl><br><br>
<textarea id="vision" name="vision" maxlength="1000" height="1000000px" rows="10" cols="100"><?php echo $row['description']; ?></textarea>
<br><br>
<?php  } ?>

<?php if($row['title']=='Mission') { ?>
<label>Mision</label><br><br>
<textarea id="mission" name="mission" maxlength="1000" height="1000000px" rows="10" cols="100"><?php echo $row['description']; ?></textarea>
<br><br>
<?php  } ?>

<?php if($row['title']=='Values') { ?>
<label>Values</label><br><br>
<textarea id="values" name="values" maxlength="1000" height="1000000px" rows="10" cols="100"><?php echo $row['description']; ?></textarea>
<br><br>

<?php  } ?>


  <?php
    }
    ?>

    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Save Changes"/>
    <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Your text areas don't have any `name` attributes, so nothing gets posted for them.

Comment: How do you expect `$_POST['vision']` to be filled in if there's no `name="vision"` in the textarea?

Comment: You also should check `$retval` after each query. Otherwise, you're just checking if the last `UPDATE` worked.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about the name. Thank you so much! It's working now. :D @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this code with your "edit_mission_vision.php" file

```
<form action="/alumni/admin/update_mission_vision.php" method="post">
<?php
    include_once 'db.php';
    $sql="SELECT * FROM about";
    $result_set=mysql_query($sql);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
    {
?>

<?php if($row['title']=='Vision') { ?>
 <label>Vision</labrl><br><br>
<textarea name="vision" id="vision" maxlength="1000" height="1000000px" rows="10" cols="100"><?php echo $row['description']; ?></textarea>
<br><br>
<?php  } ?>

<?php if($row['title']=='Mission') { ?>
<label>Mision</label><br><br>
<textarea name="mission" id="mission" maxlength="1000" height="1000000px" rows="10" cols="100"><?php echo $row['description']; ?></textarea>
<br><br>
<?php  } ?>

<?php if($row['title']=='Values') { ?>
<label>Values</label><br><br>
<textarea name="values" id="values" maxlength="1000" height="1000000px" rows="10" cols="100"><?php echo $row['description']; ?></textarea>
<br><br>

<?php  } ?>


  <?php
    }
    ?>

    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Save Changes"/>
    <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
```

if you get same value in all the three records then you need to create array and then update array in your query via while loop..
and add "[]" after name attribute of textarea.
hope it will help.

Comment: You should explain what you fixed and why, not just dump a bunch of code. Do you expect everyone who reads this to do a line-by-line comparison with the original?

Comment: Yes I will update my answer with the correct code in it :)

Answer (score 0):

1) you need to define name in your all textareas.

2) Why you need three queries in order to update single field?

Try this query :

```
update `about` set `description` =  
                  case 
                       when title='Vision' then '$vision' 
                       when title='Mission' then '$mission' 
                       when title='Values' then '$values' 
                  end
```

> Side Note : Stop using `mysql_*`. It's no more available. use
>   `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.